# Flex- define main function in the code part

Tags: gcc, lex, flex-lexer

I'm a nooby to flex.
I have a simple h.w- to read the input and to print some words acording to the input.
I'm using an hash table that is weitten in another c & h files.
herer is my code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hashtbl.h"
#include "hashtbl.c"
void add_define( char * str);
HASHTBL *my_table;
char* get_define(char * str);
%}
...
...
%%
...
...
%%


void main()
{
my_table = hashtbl_create(100, NULL);
yylex();
hashtbl_destroy(my_table);
}


void add_define( char * str)
{
...
...

}


char* get_define(char * str)
{

...
...

}
```

when I try to compile it with- gcc -ll lex.yy.c
I get an error regarding the main function-

> "multiple definition of `main` ....

I know I can compile it with - gcc lex.yy.c -lfl
but I cannot use it

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete the main function and use other ways for what I wanted to do